# Why there is nothing in the console? I am trying to learn text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code should let me read the text I have just created but I see nothing, there is no error, the console just blank, this also happens when I try to print the text file, even the readline doesn't work too.

Here is the code:

```
l=open('bla.txt', mode='a+')

l.write('zxc vbn mju\n')

l.write('asd fgh jkl\n')

l.write('qwerty uiop')

print(l.read())
```

Comment: When you read, the cursor is already at the *end* of the content you've written.

Answer (score 1):

You always need to keep track of your cursor. Your problem was that the cursor was already at the end so due that reason you wasn't able to print anything

**Solution:**

```
l=open('bla.txt', mode='a+')

l.write('zxc vbn mju\n')

l.write('asd fgh jkl\n')

l.write('qwerty uiop')

l.seek(0)

print(l.read())
```

Answer (score 0):

First write something in a file.

```
with open("Path\\To\\File.txt", "a+") as f:
    f.write("Something, something")
```

Then read

```
with open("Path\\To\\File.txt", "r+") as f:
    f.seek(0) # Sets cursor to start of file
    print(f.read())
```

Hope this helps.